# Python or Bash - Iterate all words in a text file over itself

Tags: python, bash, loops, while-loop

I have a text file that contains thousands of words, e.g:

```
laban
labrador
labradors
lacey
lachesis
lacy
ladoga
ladonna
lafayette
lafitte
lagos
lagrange
lagrangian
lahore
laius
lajos
lakeisha
lakewood
```

I want to iterate every word over itself so i get:

```
labanlaban
labanlabrador
labanlabradors
labanlacey
labanlachesis
etc...
```

In bash i can do the following, but it is extremely slow:

```
#!/bin/bash
( cat words.txt | while read word1; do
  cat words.txt | while read word2; do
    echo "$word1$word2" >> doublewords.txt
 done; done )
```

Is there a faster and more efficient way to do this?
Also, how would i iterate two different text files in this manner?

Comment: Can you fit the list into memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GHC available, Cartesian products are a synch!

**Q1: One file**

```
-- words.hs
import Control.Applicative
main = interact f
    where f = unlines . g . words
          g x = map (++) x <*> x
```

This splits the file into a list of words, and then appends each word to each other word with the applicative `<*>`.

Compile with GHC,

```
ghc words.hs
```

and then run with IO redirection:

```
./words <words.txt >out
```

**Q2: Two files**

```
-- words2.hs
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import System.Environment
main = do
    ws <- mapM ((liftM words) . readFile) =<< getArgs
    putStrLn $ unlines $ g ws
    where g (x:y:_) = map (++) x <*> y
```

Compile as before and run with the two files as arguments:

```
./words2 words1.txt words2.txt > out
```

**Bleh, compiling?**

Want the convenience of a shell script and the performance of a compiled executable? Why not do both?

Simply wrap the Haskell program you want in a wrapper script which compiles it in `/var/tmp`, and then replaces itself with the resulting executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wrapper.sh

cd /var/tmp
cat > c.hs <<CODE
# replace this comment with haskell code
CODE
ghc c.hs >/dev/null
cd - >/dev/null
exec /var/tmp/c "$@"
```

This handles arguments and IO redirection as though the wrapper didn't exist.

**Results**

Timing against some of the other answers with two 2000 word files:

```
$ time ./words2 words1.txt words2.txt >out
3.75s user 0.20s system 98% cpu 4.026 total

$ time ./wrapper.sh words1.txt words2.txt > words2
4.12s user 0.26s system 97% cpu 4.485 total

$ time ./thanatos.py > out
4.93s user 0.11s system 98% cpu 5.124 total

$ time ./styko.sh
7.91s user 0.96s system 74% cpu 11.883 total

$ time ./user3552978.sh
57.16s user 29.17s system 93% cpu 1:31.97 total
```

Comment: awesome! how about 2 different text files?

Comment: @user3552978 I've now improved the Haskell script for two different text files and updated the results.

Answer (score 2):

If you can fit the list into memory:

```
import itertools

with open(words_filename, 'r') as words_file:
    words = [word.strip() for word in words_file]

for words in itertools.product(words, repeat=2):
    print(''.join(words))
```

(You can also do a double-for loop, but I was feeling `itertools` tonight.)

I suspect the win here is that we can avoid re-reading the file over and over again; the inner loop in your bash example will cat the file one for each iteration of the outer loop. Also, I think Python just tends to execute faster than bash, IIRC.

You could certainly pull this trick with bash (read the file into an array, write a double-for loop), it's just more painful.

Comment: Thanks. That worked pretty well. What if i wanted to iterate two different text files instead of the same text file?

Comment: Load both files with the `with…` lines and use `itertools.product(words1, words2)` instead of `itertools.product(words, repeat=2)`. (see ["https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html"][here] )

Comment: Thanks for your help but i couldn't quite get this going. i tried loading both files using the same "with" but it didn't quite work (e.g. `with open('a', 'w') as a, open('b', 'w') as b:`). Tried 2 separate "with" loops and no luck either.

Comment: If you want to open two files for *reading*, you'll want `'r'` as the second argument to `open`. (`'w'` is "write", and will delete the file!)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `sed` is pretty efficient to append a text to each line.
I propose:

```
#!/bin/bash

for word in $(< words.txt)
do 
    sed "s/$/$word/" words.txt;
done > doublewords.txt
```

(Do you confuse `$` which means end of line for `sed` and `$word` which is a bash variable).

For a 2000 line file, this runs in about 20 s on my computer, compared to ~2 min for you solution.

---

Remark: it also looks like you are slightly better off redirecting the standard output of the whole program instead of forcing writes at each loop.

---

(Warning, this is a bit off topic and personal opinion!)

If you are really going for speed, you should consider using a compiled language such as C++. For example:

```
vector<string> words;
ifstream infile("words.dat");
for(string line ; std::getline(infile,line) ; )
    words.push_back(line);
infile.close();

ofstream outfile("doublewords.dat");
for(auto word1 : data)
    for(auto word2 : data)
        outfile << word1 << word2 << "\n";
outfile.close();
```

You need to understand that both bash and python  are bad at double for loops: that's why you use tricks (@Thanatos) or predefined commands (`sed`). Recently, I came across a double for loop problem (given a set of 10000 points in 3d, compute all the distances between pairs) and I successful solved it using C++ instead of python or Matlab.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give your solution a go. Also, how would i iterate two different text files instead of the same text file over itself?

Comment: The two occurences of `words.txt` are independant. Just replace the first one by `words1.txt` and the second one by `words2.txt`.

Comment: I think i'm doing something wrong here. Is this correct? `#!/bin/bash
for word in $(< doublewords.txt)
do
        sed "s/$/$word/" numbers.txt;
done > words-numbers.txt
`

Comment: @user3552978 Did you mean to put `(< doublewords.txt)` instead of `(< words.txt)`. Other than that, it looks correct (except lack of line breaks, which I assume are just from the comment).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pythonic way by creating a `tempfile` and write data to it while reading the existing file and finally `remove` the original file and `move` the new file to original file.

```
import sys
from os import remove
from shutil import move
from tempfile import mkstemp


def data_redundent(source_file_path):
    fh, target_file_path = mkstemp()
    with open(target_file_path, 'w') as target_file:
        with open(source_file_path, 'r') as source_file:
            for line in source_file:
                target_file.write(line.replace('\n', '')+line)
    remove(source_file_path)
    move(target_file_path, source_file_path)

data_redundent('test_data.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how efficient this is, but a very simple way, using the Unix tool specifically designed for this sort of thing, would be

```
paste -d'\0' <file> <file>
```

The `-d` option specifies the delimiter to be used between the concatenated parts, and `\0` indicates a NULL character (i.e. no delimiter at all).

Comment: This only outputs the doubles like "labanlaban" but not things like "labanlacey". (It just doubles each line; the OP appears to want a Cartesian product.)